# diagnosing bandwidth from dask dashboard

Tags: dask, dashboard

This may be a very silly pb but I cannot diagnose bandwidth from the dask dashboard. I am under the impression the line is always so low it is not visible, cf [screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzZYR.png).

Can I use the dashboard to get a value in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few places in the dashboard where bandwidth is mentioned:

```
workers: the read/write network bandwidth is listed real-time per worker
bandwidth-per-workers: the aggregate bandwidth is accumulated per worker pairs
bandwidth-per-type: the aggregate bandwidth is accumulated per type of data
```

Some of these are more accessible in the performance_report, which may interest you. See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html#capture-diagnostics